# Web3.js Script exits while listening to CreatedPairs

Tags: node.js, web3js

I am trying to create a simple script to test the event listening functionality of Web3.js `CreatedPairs`. However, my script runs through the code once and then exits instead of continuing to listen for created pairs and I cannot figure out why.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'https://mynodeishere');

const IUniswapV2Factory = require("@uniswap/v2-core/build/IUniswapV2Factory.json")
const UNI_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f'
const uFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Factory.abi, UNI_FACTORY_ADDRESS)


const main = async () => {

    // Create event listener to listen to PairCreated
    uFactory.events.PairCreated({}, async (error, event) => {
    
        console.log(`New pair detected...\n`)

    })
}

main()
```

What ends up happening is when I run `node ./myapp.js`. The code gets stepped in to and logs `New pair detected...` to the console and then exits. This happening right away tells me that it is not executing when a new pair is detected and is instead just stepping through the code.

However, what I anticipated happening, was for the app to continue to run and log to the console only when a new pair is detected. I am sure I am overlooking something small, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `Web3.givenProvider` is `null`, so the HTTP provider is used.

To be able to subscribe to events, you need to use a WSS provider.

```
// example connection to a WSS provider
const web3 = new Web3('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/<yourtoken>');
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!